# jQuery click vs swipe

Tags: jquery, click, swipe

I'm working on an iPad specific website, and what I'm looking to do is have a  be swipe-able. Inside the  there will be questions that the person can answer (questions are in the normal HTML  tag).

Now, I can get the swipe working fine, but when I click the questions (checkbox, radio buttons, etc.) nothing happens. How can I work around this?

I understand that the touchstart is used to detect and move things around but how do I ignore that when the user tries to click something that's supposed to be clickable?

**Updated**
After much research, I decided to use touchwipe. It was easy to use/implement and didn't override the click functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise using jQueryMobile for your site. Not only does it come with some nice CSS/JS for mobile sites, but you can also take advantage of its custom events that detect swiping:

- `swipe`
- `swiperight`
- `swipeleft`

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with touchwipe.